# How do I identify the length of random substrings within a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have a long vector of 1s and 0s and I want to find some function that will give me a vector with the length of each continuous list of 1s within that vector.  For example, the vector I have looks like this:

```
c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)
```

And I'd like to get an output that looks like this (where each value in the output is the length of the next continuous length of 1s in the input vector):

```
c(6,1,3,4)
```

Then I can run any stats I need to on that output vector.  The length of the repeating/intervening zeros is random and the actual data set I have is a vector about 20000 elements long so there's no way I can do it by hand.

Any thoughts?  I've been stuck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle` from `base R` and extract the `lengths` based on the logical vector of 'values'

```
with(rle(as.logical(v1)), lengths[values])
#[1] 6 1 3 4
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I didn't know about the rle function. Thank you!